# Centralising specflow data from feature files?

Tags: design-patterns, automated-tests, specflow

Specflow data can be expressed by scenarios in feature file through the use of tables.

If you have a lot of scenarios I imagine it is difficult to locate and change the data.

Is there a pattern that helps populate the feature file with data for each scenario? 
ie how can a repository be used to centralise data across many features?

Comment: I read your question twice and I'm still not sure what you are asking. Are you asking whether you can dump multiple scenarios into the same feature file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at how you've written the question it seems like you are new to Specflow.

The problem is that Specflow is not a programming language. In fact several of its language components can get in the way when you first start looking at it.

If you are follow the BDD methodology properly, it isn't programmers that should be writing feature files. It should be business people, that's why the language is so open. Just a couple of placeholders to give the feature and scenarios names, and then a simple word at the start of every line to indicate if it is a setup action (Given), and operation (When) or a test (Then).

For example, As a developer I might come up with the following as an example.

```
Feature: Waking kids up for school
Scenario Outline: When its a school day
  Given it is a <day>
  When it is <time> for <child> to get up
  Then <Mum> should wake me up

Examples:
  |child   |day|time |parent|
  |daughter|mon|06:30|mum   |
  |son     |mon|06:30|mum   |
  |daughter|tue|06:30|mum   |
  |son     |tue|06:30|mum   |
  |daughter|wed|07:00|dad   |
  |son     |wed|07:15|dad   |
  |daughter|thu|07:00|dad   |
  |son     |thu|07:15|dad   |
  |daughter|fri|07:30|dad   |
  |son     |fri|07:35|dad   |
```

And this example would encapsulate all the complexities of our (fictional) household routine with different parents favouring different times and days of the week or whatever.

But on the other hand I could also write

```
Feature: Waking kids up for school
Scenario: When its a school day
  Given it is a school day
  When it is time to get up
  Then my parent should wake me up
```

This could capture all that was necessary, because the complexity doesn't need to be reflected in the scenarios (seriously who cares when my kids wake up, as long as they get to school!).

But if you need the complexity, you could define it in your testing code

```
[Binding]
public void GivenItIsASchoolDay()
{
  ScenarioContext.Current["Day"]="Wed";
  ScenarioContext.Current["Time"]="07:00";
  ScenarioContext.Current["Parent"]="Mum";
}
```

Don't forget that the `Binding`s are global, so if you structure your code so they are all in the same place, well you've ended up with everything centralised.